# Access Query multiple table, concatenate and remove duplicates

Tags: database, multiple-columns

I've attached an Example Database with unfinished query that I am looking for help with, image shows what https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9829095/Result.jpg

Example Database: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9829095/Song-V2.accdb

Comment: [Working solution from Duane Hookom](http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/generic-function-to-concatenate-child-records_topic16.html).

Answer (score 0):

[**Working solution from Duane Hookom**](http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/generic-function-to-concatenate-child-records_topic16.html).
Example according to your structure:

```sql
SELECT distinct ID
,Concatenate("SELECT distinct Genre FROM qrySong4Export WHERE ID =" & [ID]) as Genre
,Concatenate("SELECT distinct Artist FROM qrySong4Export WHERE ID =" & [ID]) as Artist
from qrySong4Export
```

Output:

```
ID  Genre   Artist
1   Genre 2, Genre 8    6, 12
2   Genre 9 1, 17
3   Genre 10, Genre 13  5
4   Genre 12    4, 5
```

Code (add it Create -> Module -> [Paste]):

```vb
Function Concatenate(pstrSQL As String, _
        Optional pstrDelim As String = ", ") _
        As String
'Created by Duane Hookom, 2003
'this code may be included in any application/mdb providing
'   this statement is left intact
'example
'tblFamily with FamID as numeric primary key
'tblFamMem with FamID, FirstName, DOB,...
'return a comma separated list of FirstNames
'for a FamID
' John, Mary, Susan
'in a Query
'SELECT FamID,
'Concatenate("SELECT FirstName FROM tblFamMem
' WHERE FamID =" & [FamID]) as FirstNames
'FROM tblFamily
'

'======For DAO uncomment next 4 lines=======
'====== comment out ADO below =======
    'Dim db As DAO.Database
    'Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    'Set db = CurrentDb
    'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(pstrSQL)

'======For ADO uncomment next two lines=====
'====== comment out DAO above ======
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open pstrSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, _
    adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    Dim strConcat As String 'build return string
    With rs
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                strConcat = strConcat & _
                .Fields(0) & pstrDelim
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
'====== uncomment next line for DAO ========
    'Set db = Nothing
    If Len(strConcat) > 0 Then
        strConcat = Left(strConcat, _
        Len(strConcat) - Len(pstrDelim))
    End If
    Concatenate = strConcat
End Function
```

Comment: I've tried this before doesn't seem to work for my case, as I have ARTIST and GENRE both are needed to concatenate and separated by a comma.

Comment: hi revoua,I got this error https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9829095/Clipboard01.jpg

Comment: Tools -> References: check Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 (or available) and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library